# If Javascript's native OOP is classless, what about the constructor? Doesn't that imply a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I think Javascript native OOP system is said to be classless, and is object-based, not class-based.  But every example I see always start with a constructor similar to

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Just by using a constructor this way, doesn't this already imply a class is being used?  (a class called Person)

---

Details:

If we can use

```
a.__proto__ = b;
```

on any Javascript platform, then I think it is classless.  But we can't do that.  If we want that behavior, we need to use

```
function F() { }
F.prototype = b;
a = new F();
```

and so, a constructor *has to* be used.  So if constructor is such a cornerstone in Javascript, that means it is intended to be constructor of Person, Widget, etc, and these are classes.

Comment: Why would the use of a function make it any more class-full than the use of a variable assignation? You can create structured objects in plain old **C** with **struct**s and use a function such as `new_Person()` to make it look like a class. But you're still using OOP structures in a classless environment.

Comment: Check out [QOO](http://news.qooxdoo.org/download-qxoo-now) it's an OOP "class-full" abstraction written in/for JavaScript. It's part of the [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/) framework which builds upon this abstraction and implements a whole application-oriented library for JavaScript.

Comment: There is another abstraction called [Objective-J]() which is similarly supporting a framework that I know less about [Cappuccino Application Framework](http://cappuccino.org/) but this one isn't *native* JavaScript it's *compiled to* JavaScript (on the fly).

Comment: And then there's [Coffee Script](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) but this one isn't *native* JavaScript either it's *compiled to* JavaScript (on the fly)

Answer (score 5):

The OOP in Javascript is slightly different from, for instance, the Java OOP.
The Javascript constructors do not refer to a class definition (so it is classless). Rather the constructor refers to a prototype. The base of the OOP in Javascript is the Object object (not the Object class), from where all the others objects are derived.

Prototyping grants you inheritance, and the possibility to extend an existing object with properties and methods.

I suggest you [this article](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html).

In your example:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Mike = new Person('Mike');
```

the Person() function lets you create a new object prototyped on the `Object` object with a new property called `name`. Well, such a kind of function in Javascript oop is called a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Classless may be an inaccurate way to describe JavaScript's approach on OOP.

JavaScript does lack *class definitions*.

It also lacks a class-to-object correspondence.

You can't check if an object instantiated with a constructor such as `Person` is *of class* `Person`.

You can check if it contains the expected object members and conclude that it is of the expected class.

But if the object members have been changed along the way you're not going to get the desired/expected result.

### TL;DR

JavaScript exposes *constructors* (appropriately named *prototypes*) as a manner in which you can define a template for constructing plain objects.

The important thing is that the end result of a prototype call is **a plain object** with some predefined members and not **an object of a certain class** .

Comment: Wouldn't you consider `instanceof` to provide class-to-object correspondence? `fred instanceof Person;` http://jsfiddle.net/9BwBA/

Comment: Yes i do but since it can be overridden on the fly at runtime there is no guarantee that that behavior is consistent. For example you have a framework such as `qxoo` and you implement a "down-casting" or an "up-casting" facility (i don't know if they do) that changes the prototype of the object. Where is your god now?

Comment: Check [my edit](http://jsfiddle.net/9BwBA/1/) on your fiddle: I've mutated fred and turned him into a window, poor fred.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to think of javascript as a classless environment.  If you think javascript classes you should be able to assume there's certain useful things you can do when there are classes and they're strictly enforced.  However those certain useful things you cannot assume.  The presence of something that looks like a constructor does not indicate you're creating a class.

For example, let's say you `var dude = Person('Ashton Kutcher')`.  Now, when you `dude instanceOf person`, you get true.  You assume you have the properties and methods of a person.  What if some code comes along and says `dude.personMethod = undefined`.  Now, while `dude instanceOf person` will still be true, the `personMethod` is no longer available.

You can think of javascript as having classes but it's a leaky abstraction.  It's better to think of javascript as having a prototypal inheritance system when it comes to determining what something is and what you can expect of it.

More information here: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: Check [my edit](http://jsfiddle.net/9BwBA/1/) on @user1689607's fiddle: I've mutated fred and turned him into a window, poor fred.

Comment: so I think Crockford's `Object.create()` made it to ECMA-262 or ECMAScript 5.1.  I wonder if it is called `Object.createFrom()` or `Object.inheritFrom()` maybe it is more accurate?

Answer (score -2):

Create a class using the  Object Constructor and prototyping can help us
in creating many instances of the class without redefining the object each time wee need it.

so in the above example

```
function Person(name)


 {
    this.name = name;
}
```

you can create two persons with different names.
example :

var personA = new Person();
personA.name = "james";

var personB = new Person();
personB.name = "Tom";

alert(personA.name + personB.name);

i suggest you reading this link will be helpful 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml

Comment: -1 you are not answering the question. OP knows that JavaScript allows this kind of behavior. He's asking why JavaScript is often called "classless".